# how to resolve the error in this code

Tags: java

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   at javaPracticeqo.Givemetriangle.main(Givemetriangle.java:5)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
package JavaPracticeqo;
public class Givemetriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        s=sc.nextInt();
         for(int i=s;i>0;i--) //rows 
         {
             for(int j=1;j<s;j++)
             {
                 System.out.println("*");
             }
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: javaPracticeqo or JavaPracticeqo ?

Comment: The `package` directive should be the first statement in the file. I can't reproduce the error with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below :-

```
package JavaPracticeqo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Givemetriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int s = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = s; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j < s; j++) {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

However, it will not print triangle as you want. I have just refactored your code. Please go through Java Programming Language.

1. Package must be the first statement.
2. Package name should be in lower case.
3. Scanner should be closed after use.

Answer (score 0):

the package name must be first

```
package JavaPracticeqo;
```

then the classes needed to be imported

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

the last is the class and it will be like this to draw a triangle using stars

```
public class Givemetriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number :");
        int s = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = s; i > 1; i--) {
            s = s - 1;
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int j = 1; j < s; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```